# GNU Octave installation problem with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: octave

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Vostro laptop and then tried installing GNU octave using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install octave
```

After the installation, when I type octave in the terminal I get the octave critical error message:

```
 **Octave critical error**

 **The settings file /home/siva/.config/octave/qt-settings does not exist and can not be created. Make sure that you have read and write permissions to /home/siva/.config/octave**

**Octave GUI must be closed now.**
```

Can someone please help me fix this problem?

Comment: Can you do `ls -dl /home/siva/.config/octave` and let us know what it says?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 16 12:52 /home/siva/.config/octave

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. `/home/siva/.config/octave` should not be owned by `root`, so I am not sure what you did. Nonetheless, I wrote an answer below to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, `ls -dl /home/siva/.config/octave` shows that the directory is owned by `root`, but it should have been owned by `siva`. To fix this, run:

```
sudo chown -R siva:siva /home/siva/.config/octave
```

Your Octave installation should now proceed without permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gksu` installed, in a terminal do `gksu nautilus ~/.config` then locate a folder named **octave**, right click, choose **Properties**, and under **Permissions** tab, change the **Owner** and **Group** to your username, and also change their **Access** to Create and delete files. Inside octave folder there is a file named qt-settings, do the same as you do on octave folder, but change the Access to Read and write.

If you don't have `gksu`, just install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

This also works for Ubuntu 16.04